# getting items from LocalStorage gives an error when I try to loop through the items

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a small project where I try to load some stuff from LocalStorage and append it to my html page.

here's what it looks like:

```
function fetchList() {
    var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
    var listList = document.getElementById('listList');

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    .....stuff
    }
```

I have it set so that I call this function in my body tag

```
<body onload="fetchList()">
```

I currently have nothing saved in local storage and it's giving me an error on the FOR loop statement, especially .length. I understand there's nothing there, but wouldn't it just skip to end of loop ?

instead it give sme this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Length' of null

Is there a reason why this wouldn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I currently have nothing saved in local storage` which is why `.getItem('list')` returns **null** - what were you expecting if you have nothing in localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's nothing in storage yet, JSON.parse() will return `null`.
So then `var list` will also be `null`.

And `null` does not have a `length` property, explaining your error, since a for loop based around the length of something needs that length to be a number.

Try detecting the existance of the JSON string first:

```
var storedJSON = localStorage.getItem('list');
if ( storedJSON ) {
  var list = JSON.parse( storedJSON  );
  // continue code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to check if null first

```
if (variable == null){
    // your code here.
}
```